# Do something in middle of recursive function, then return as needed

Tags: ruby, recursion

How do I do something in the middle of a recursion, and return as needed? In other words, maybe no more recursion is needed because I have found a "solution" in which case to save resources, the recursion can stop.

For example, let's say I have a working `permute` method that does this

```
permute([["a","b"],[1,2]])
>>> [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

Rather than have the method generate all 4 possibilities, if one meets my requirements, I'd like it to stop. For example, let's say I'm searching for `["a",2]`, then the method can stop after it creates the second possibility.

This is my current `permute` method that is working

```
def permute(arr)
  if arr.length == 1
    return arr.first
  else
    first = arr.shift
    return first.product(permute(arr)).uniq 
  end
end
```

I feel like I need to inject a `do` block somewhere with something like the below, but not sure how/where...

```
if result_of_permutation_currently == ["a",2]
   return ...
else
   # continuing the permutations
end
```

Comment: @james : It seems to me that you want to use co-routines: Your function calculates things, returns answers to the caller, but then continue to execute. Maybe a [Fiber](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Fiber.html) would be a solution. Or, if you just need a callback to the callers side, accept an optional [block](http://www.mattsears.com/articles/2011/11/27/ruby-blocks-as-dynamic-callbacks/) argument, into which you yield your results.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I edited the question, let me know if that helps clarify!

Comment: Excellent!.....

Comment: @user1934428, `Array#product` does not take an optional block. Were you referring to something else?

Comment: I didn't mean to use it with `Array#product`, but to the `permute` function the OP wrote. He wants pass values back to the caller, and then continue the permutation. One possibility is to check whether the caller supplied a block, and yield to this block the interim result (or whatever he wants to report to the caller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your method as follows.

```
def partial_product(arr, last_element)
  @a = []
  @last_element = last_element
  recurse(arr)
  @a
end
```

```
def recurse(arr, element = [])
  first, *rest = arr
  if rest.empty?
    first.each do |e|
      el = element + [e]
      @a << el
      return true if el == @last_element
    end
  else
    first.each do |e|
      rv = recurse(rest, element + [e])
      return true if rv
    end
  end
  false
end
```

```
arr = [["a","b"], [1,2,3], ["cat","dog"]]
```

```
partial_product(arr, ["b",2,"dog"])
  #=> [["a", 1, "cat"], ["a", 1, "dog"], ["a", 2, "cat"],
  #    ["a", 2, "dog"], ["a", 3, "cat"], ["a", 3, "dog"],
  #    ["b", 1, "cat"], ["b", 1, "dog"], ["b", 2, "cat"],
  #    ["b", 2, "dog"]]
partial_product(arr, ["a",1,"dog"])
  #=> [["a", 1, "cat"], ["a", 1, "dog"]] 
partial_product(arr, ["b",2,"pig"])
  #=> [["a", 1, "cat"], ["a", 1, "dog"], ["a", 2, "cat"],
  #    ["a", 2, "dog"], ["a", 3, "cat"], ["a", 3, "dog"],
  #    ["b", 1, "cat"], ["b", 1, "dog"], ["b", 2, "cat"],
  #    ["b", 2, "dog"], ["b", 3, "cat"], ["b", 3, "dog"]]
```

If you prefer to avoid using instance variables, you could carry `a` and `last_element` as arguments in `recurse`, but there would be inefficiencies by doing so, particularly in terms of memory use.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with this! Just some clarification questions as I try to understand this. the `@last_element` passed to `partial_product` represents the combination that you're searching for (i.e., what will cause the recursion to stop), correct? `@a` represents the array of all the recursive options that have been examined thus far, correct?

Comment: In terms of your question, the second argument passed to `partial_product` would be `["a",2]`. That is the argument `last_element`, which is save as the value of the instance variable `@last_element`. It never changes, so rather than passing `last_element` to `recurse` I decided to just make it an instance variable that is visible to `recurse`...

Comment: ... `@a` is the array you are building. Suppose `@last_element = ["b",1]`. In terms of `[["a","b"], [1,2]]` from the question, `@a` is initially empty, then is `[["a",1]]`, then is `[["a",1], ["a",2]]`, then is `[["a",1], ["a",2], ["b",1]]`, at which point we are finished (because the last element equals @last_element), so `recurse` will immediately return `true` to it's caller, which in turn will immediately return `true` to its caller, and so on, until `recurse` returns `true` to `partial_product`. In short, your understanding is corrrect. Maybe I should have just said that. :-)

Comment: got it ok. curious, I realized after asking this question, that what was making this harder than it should be is the fact that i was reliant on using `product`, an already-defined method in Ruby. I should have just done the permutation myself, at which point I can inject whatever logic I want. This is kind of like your solution, where `recurse` is probably very similar to how Ruby's `product` actually works under the hood, right? EDIT: well i looked at the source code... so... not the same, but I think the methodology still makes sense

Comment: I doubt that the author of `Array#product` used a recursive method. See my other answer, which gives two non-recursive solutions. I suspect both are more efficient than a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways that could be done without using recursion.

**Use `each` to generate elements of the desired array until the target pair is reached**

```
def permute(arr1, arr2, last_pair = [])
  arr1.each_with_object([]) do |e1,a|
    arr2.each do |e2|
      a << [e1, e2]
      break a if [e1, e2] == last_pair
    end
  end
end
```

```
permute(["a","b"],[1,2],["b", 1])
  #=> [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1]]
permute(["a","b"],[1,2],["b", 99])
  #=> [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["b", 2]] 
permute(["a","b"],[1,2])
  #=> [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["b", 2]] 
permute(["a","b"],[],["b", 1])
  #=> [] 
permute([],[1,2],["b", 1])
  #=> [] 
permute([],[],["b", 1])
  #=> []
```

**Map a sequence of the indices of the desired array**

```
def permute(arr1, arr2, last_pair = [])
  n1 = arr1.size
  n2 = arr2.size
  idx1 = arr1.index(last_pair.first)
  idx2 = idx1.nil? ? nil : arr2.index(last_pair.last)
  return arr1.product(arr2) if idx2.nil?
  0.step(to: idx1*n2+idx2).
    map {|i| [arr1[(i % (n1*n2))/n2], arr2[i % n2]]}
end
```

```
permute(["a","b"],[1,2],["b", 1])
```

See [Numeric#step](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step)

`idx1*n2 + idx2`, the number of elements in the array to be returned, is computed as follows.

```
last_pair = ["b", 1]
n2 = arr2.size 
  #=> 2 
idx1 = arr1.index(last_pair.first)
  #=> 1 
idx2 = idx1.nil? ? nil : arr2.index(last_pair.last)      
    #=> 0 
  idx1*n2 + idx2
    #=> 2
```

The element at index `i` of the array returned is:

```
n1 = arr1.size
  #=> 2
[arr1[(i % (n1*n2))/n2], arr2[i % n2]]
  #=> [["a","b"][(i % 2*2)/2], [1,2][i % 2]]
```

For `i = 1` this is

```
[["a","b"][(1 % 4)/2], [1,2][1 % 2]]
  #=> [["a","b"][0], [1,2][1]]
  #=> [“a”, 2]
```

For `i = 2` this is

```
[["a","b"][(2 % 4)/2], [1,2][2 % 2]]
  #=> [["a","b"][1], [1,2][0]]
  #=> [“b”,1]
```

---

Note that we cannot write

```
arr1.lazy.product(arr2).first(idx1*n2+idx2+1)
```

because `arr1.lazy` returns an enumerator (`arr1.lazy
 #=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: ["a", "b"]>`) but [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) requires it's receiver to be an array. It's for that reason that some Rubyists would like to see `product` made an `Enumerable` method (with a `lazy` version), but don't hold your breathe.

Comment: This was my original answer. I deleted it after I realized that the question only was only concerned with a recursive solution. I undeleted it in view of the OP's comments on my other answer.

Comment: i think the recursion makes more sense, because in my use case, there is any number of `arr1, arr2, arr3...`

Comment: My opinion stands, but a benchmark might be interesting.